# Where can I find administrative boundary data for Mexico?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, mexico

The USA has states, counties, and cities.

How are Mexico's territories split up, hierarchically?

It also has states and cities, but does it have an intermediate-level political unit?

Where might I find sets of boundary data for such units?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_divisions_of_Mexico) discusses this topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geography trivia.

Comment: No, it isn't? I am working on a web project. I have to split up information within the USA as...

Country/State/County/City

I am trying to identify the best way to structure Mexico in the same way. So far I have determined as follows.

Mexico/State/City

Is there another level to it, as their is within America?

Comment: I've suggested an edit. It adds "And where might I find sets of boundary data for such units?" to help bring it *on* topic.